The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below, Please Select another theme
I'm a beginner Ubuntu user. I'm on Ubuntu 24.04.1 using KDE Plasma and custom themes.
This message appeared after I was trying to make DaVinci Resolve work downloading packages.
There was another similar question, but I did not manage to make it work.
I tried sudo apt update which seems to run fine except a few packages giving an error message (-5 no address associated with hostname).
The packages which get this error message:
   dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease 
   debian.sur5r.net/i3/dists/noble/InRelease 
   archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease 
   archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease 
   archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease 
   archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease 
   repo.waydro.id/dists/noble/InRelease 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm-theme-McMojave gets this error message: E: Unable to locate package sddm-theme-McMojave
